# Separating variables in differential equations with several functions of the same variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So far I've only seen how to solve some ordinary differential equations with several methods, in particular with separation of variables which the first method taught for being the simplest one.

But I've sometimes encountered equations with several functions of the same variable, and I've been told that separating variables would do the job, however I wasn't taught that on the corresponding **ODE** course. This is the example I'm facing right now:

$$\tan{\beta}\cdot u'=v'\cdot\sin{u}$$

Where both $u=u(t), v=v(t)$ are functions of the same variable, $\beta$ is just a constant. My question is, how to attack this kind of equations, how to "separate variables" here, are there some general guidelines to solve them (maybe under some conditions, for instance the variable $t$ doesn't appear here)?

How about this example in particular, what makes it solvable and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:
$$\tan(\beta)\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dt}\sin(u)$$
$$\tan(\beta)\frac{du}{\sin(u)}=dv$$
$$v=\tan(\beta)\int\frac{du}{\sin(u)}$$
So, you can integrate and find the relationship between $u$ and $v$.

Since you have only one equation and two unknown functions $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ you can only obtain a relationship between the two functions, but not the expression of each one.

Comment: Oh I see, so the solution has a degree of freedom, so to speak? For instance, the solution to that integral is $\log{\tan{\frac{u}{2}}}$, then the solutions to the equation would be the pairs $(u(t),v(t))=(u,\tan{\beta}\log{\tan{\frac{u}{2}}}+C)$, right? It seems like the idea is to use Leibniz notation to get rid of the $dt$ then?

Comment: @ LMartin : OK. That is the simplest way on my viewpoint.

Comment: Perfect, you saved my day heh. Btw, what if the variable $t$ appeared in the equation, would this technique still work?

Comment: This might be ambiguous. To be clear, what example do you have in mind ?

Comment: Maybe something like $u'=v'\cdot\sin{u}\cdot t$ or $u'=v'\cdot\sin{u}+t^2$, that is, the variable is explicitly present in the equation. EDIT: Maybe just doing the same while treating $t$ as a constant since we're integrating with respect to $u$ or $v$?

Comment: For the first, what is the meaning of the dot above the $t$ ? For the second, again the goal is to find a relationship between $u$ and $v$ that is, if one is given, the relationship gives the other. Suppose $u(t)$ given. then : $$v(t)=\int \frac{u'-t^2}{\sin(u(t)}dt$$. The possibility to express  $u(t)$ as a function of $v(t)$ is more complicated and the faisability depends on the kind of function $u(t)$ is. If this is not known, one cannot give a definitive answer about the possibility to do it.

Comment: That dot was a misprint by myself, sorry. Thanks for the answer. It looks like it's not possible anymore to integrate with respect to $u$?, that is,  treating $t$ as a constant. For example, with $u'=v'\cdot \sin{u}\cdot t$, doing $v=\frac{1}{t}\int{\frac{du}{\sin{u}}}$.

Comment: If $v=\frac{1}{t}\int \frac{du}{\sin(u)}$ then $v'=\frac{1}{t}\frac{1}{\sin(u)}-\frac{1}{t^2}\int \frac{du}{\sin(u)}$ which doesn't solve the equation.

Comment: Generally, in case of two unknown functions $u(t)$ and $v(t)$, a system of two equations is given for example $u'=f(u,v)$ and $v'=g(u,v)$. This leads to an ODE  : $\frac{dv}{du}=\frac{g(u,v)}{f(u,v)}$ wich is analytically solvable only in a few cases. If solvable (then $v(u)$ obtained), it is even more difficult to express $u(t)$ and $v(y)$ in general.

Comment: Thanks for your time, everything is solved now I think.